# php !isset and empty not working

Tags: php, mysql, isset

Pulling my hair out on this, it has to be obvious, but I can't see it today.

I built a small monitoring tool for an app we have.  I want to do a check in the DB to make sure the backend scripts are working and the data isn't stale by more than 15 min.  When no records are returned in a certain timeframe it should pop up a message saying to check the script.  If they are not returned it should be an empty dataset and I should get a message on it.

Problem is, I can't get empty() or !isset to work.  Actually regardless of whether I use !empty(), empty(), isset() or !isset(), my $tripped variable never gets tripped.  I have this working for other alerts, but this one seems to be stubborn and I don't see what I'm missing.

PS I know mysql_ is out of date.

The relevant piece of code:

```
    $ldap_check = mysql_query("SELECT 
*
 FROM ldap_conns
 WHERE DATETIME > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
order by DATETIME DESC
LIMIT 1");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ldap_check))

  {
        if (empty($row['DATETIME']))
            {
            echo '<b><font color=blue><a href="server_check.php">Stale Data</a>: </font> <font color=red>LDAP data is old, check script!</font><br>' . $row['DATETIME'];
            $tripped='Yes';
            }
  }

            if ($tripped!='Yes')
            {
                echo '<a href="server_check.php"><b><font color=blue>Stale Data</a>: ' . $row['DATETIME'] . '</font></b> <font color=green> No Problems Found<br></font>';
            }
```

Comment: `empty($foo)` is pretty much the equivalent of `if ($foo == '')`, and can evaluate to true in many situations where no sane person would ever consider the var as empty. e.g. `$foo = 0; var_dump(empty($foo))` actually dumps boolean true, because in php `0 == ''` is true. Why don't you add an `echo $row['DATETIME']` OUTSIDE of your `if()` test so you can see exactly what's coming back from the DB?

Comment: have you done a var_dump of $row['DATETIME']? what does it contain, is it truly empty, or contains something like 00/00/00 00:00:00

Comment: Also compare strings with !== rather than !=.

Comment: You could start by doing a row_count to see if rows were returned. If the count is 0 then don't move to your while loop

Comment: WRONG `if ($tripped!='Yes')` RIGHT `if ($tripped!=='Yes')` though i would use actual booleans, not strings

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments.  I just did a var_dump of $row['DATETIME'] and it comes back with NULL.  Also changed the string comparison, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong... Want just check if there exists any old items? Use count! There is no reason for selectin g ALL fields from ALL records from the table. This is wrong using of database! Use count, and make index on DATETIME field!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
    count(*) old_items
FROM
    ldap_conns
WHERE
    DATETIME < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($row['old_items']) {
   echo 'There is '.$row['old_items'].' old items!';
}
```

Comment: It comes back with zero rows returned.  How do I do it right?  Would love any instruction, just teaching this to myself so don't need any bad habits. :)  Even the example you gave never sets $tripped to true, that's the part I think I'm missing.

Comment: Sheesh, why I didn't I think of doing a count?  So obvious...  That's what I get for trying to be developer.  The only thing is your provided query will also show data when the data is current since old data will still be in the DB and be counted.  I think I can come up with something from here though.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, messed around with this based on you sending me in the right direction.  Here's what I have and it seems to be working.  `$ldap_check = mysql_query("SELECT 
    count(*) as old_items
FROM
    ldap_conns
WHERE
    DATETIME > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)");


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ldap_check);

  if (!$row['old_items'])`

Answer (score 2):

You have this condition in your query:

```
WHERE DATETIME > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

So I don't see how `$row['DATETIME']` could ever be empty for any of the rows fetched (although you are actually only fetching one row...).

Comment: Even when zero rows are returned?

Comment: When zero rows are returned, the while loop will be executed ... ZERO times, so there is absolutely no checking of any query return value, because there is none. You should check the number of returned results instead. If it is zero, no up to date entries are found - which probably is not the best idea because you expect ALL entries to be up to date, and none of them stale.